# How do I trouble shoot my invoice issue

Tags: magento2, invoice

Recently Some of my invoice found in my admin panel not showing a proper page, just like showing Plain text page, how do I trouble shoot what's wrong with the invoice? just randomly happen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can press F12 and open console to see if there's any red line.

Also, check your var/log; var/report folders to see if it has any information there (clear the folder first, then open the invoice page, then check the folder again, this will help you save time identify new errors)

In my experience, it's something related to third modules or any changes that was made related to sales order